# node.js Cannot read property 'user_id'

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions, firebase-notifications

I'm new to Android and I am working with the Notifications, but I tried all the link related to mine and still got the same error. Any help would be appreciated. Advance Thank you

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = 
functions.database.ref('/notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}')
.onWrite((change, event) => {

    const user_id = event.params.user_id;
    const notification = event.params.notification;

    console.log('We have a notification to send to: ', user_id);

    if(!event.data.val())
    {
        return console.log('A Notification has been deleted from database: ', notification_id);
    }

    const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${user_id}/device_token`).once('value');

    return deviceToken.then(result => {

        const token_id = result.val();

            const payload = {
              notification: {
                title: "Message Request",
                body: "You've received a Message Request",
                icon: "logo.png"
            }
        };

        return admin.messaging().sendtoDevice(token_id, payload).then(response =>{

            console.log('This was the Notification Feature');
            return true;
        });
    });
});
```

and i got this consistent error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined
at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite.event (/user_code/index.js:9:31)at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:105:23)
at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:135:20)
at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:744:24
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a version of the Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions that is under v1.0.

For SDK version < 1.0, `event.params.user_id` will throw an error. As a matter of fact, version 1.0.0 of the Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions introduces some important changes in the API, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#realtime-database

You should verify in your `package.json` file which version of `firebase-functions` you are using.